# How to stretch a chart by width in BIRT

Tags: birt

I'm trying to stretch a chart by width in BIRT. I set up the width and height to 100% :

[image]

but anyway the chart occupies only about 50% of the area, rather than full width of the page:

[image]

And in the result html report the chart is displayed by following rules:

```
<style type="text/css">
   ...
   .style_5 { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
   ...
</style>

<div>
    <embed class="style_5" id="__bookmark_3" onresize="document.getElementById('__bookmark_3').reload()" type="image/svg+xml" src="image/custom4.svg" alt="" style=" width: 572.25pt; height: 286.125pt;display: block;">
    </embed>
</div>
```

So this `style` attribute with fixed width override the right style (`"style_5"`), and if I manually delete this `style` attribute, I see what I wish - the stretched chart. But how to force BIRT not no add that  <strike>fucking</strike> `style` attribute?

How to stretch a chart to the full width of the page?

**UPD**

I tried also to import *.css* style for the chart with the following content:

```
.embed {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

but anyway it seems to be converted in plain `width: 100%;` after import.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like setting charts size in %'s makes it default to the embed element.
Try providing the actual value:

```
.chart {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: gray;
    margin: 5pt;
    height: 1000pt;
    width: 900pt;
}
```